# Sybase: Can't CREATE DATABASE: Why not?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

This should be simple.

The [Sybase docs ("Example 1")](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X75308.htm) say you don't have to specify the `size` parameter but even if I do:

```
create database pubs5 on default = '10M'
```

I still get an error :

```
Could not execute statement.
CREATE DATABASE failed because of incorrectly specified or unavailable
space. Total number of megabytes specified and available must be at
least 6 megabytes so Model Database can be copied to the new database.
SQLCODE=1810
```

I've tried different sizes (all over 6MB), removing the size and trying double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes.

Why is this so difficult?

Thanks.

Comment: And how much space do you have?

Comment: My C drive has 266GB spare.

Comment: And C is your default?

Comment: Yes, I only have one physical drive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but there is just not sufficient space on your Sybase database device that is marked as default.

The simplest way of solving it is as follows:

```
disk resize name='master', size='20m'

create database pubs5 on master = '10M'
```

This extends the master device by 20MB, giving you space to create the database on it. Depending on your setup, your original command may also success after the 'disk resize' command.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting due to the size of master device, which already contains the system databases like model, sybsystemprocs, sybsystemdb, tempdb.

and when you run

**create database pubs5 on default = '10M'**

it used the default device (master)

so it is better to use **disk init** command to create the separate device for the user/optional dbs.